# How to validate string length with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My validation is:

```
LocationSchema.path('code').validate(function(code) {
  return code.length === 2;
}, 'Location code must be 2 characters');
```

as I want to enforce that the `code` is always 2 characters.

In my schema, I have:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
    required: true,
  },
```

I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` however when my code runs. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The field "code" is validated even if it is undefined so you must check if it has a value:

```
LocationSchema.path('code').validate(function(code) {
  return code && code.length === 2;
}, 'Location code must be 2 characters');
```

Answer (score 42):

Much simpler with this:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 2
  },
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators

Comment: If you're gonna use this, you will need to add minlength of 2 as well

Answer (score 3):

The **exact** string length is like:

```
...
minlength: 2,
maxlength: 2,
...
```